# Cannot catch Metamask Exceptions

Tags: typescript, metamask, ethers.js

i am trying to call a smartcontract with ethers.contract and the signer from ethers.providers.web3Provider to use MetaMask.In case the transaction fails i want to catch the error and try again or call a different function but my project just fails without catching the error from metamask. In case i reject the transaction on metaMask it works fine. Here is part of my code: `

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { SignedChannel } from "../api/contractTypes/channel";
import { Web3Provider } from "../client/Provider";

export async function register(
  params: SignedChannel,
  adj: ethers.Contract,
  provider: ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider | Web3Provider
) {
  const registerParams = [params.serialize(), []];
  console.log("Calling register");
  const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
  const tx = await adj.functions["register"](...registerParams, {
    from: params.params.participants[0],
    gasPrice: gasPrice.mul(2),
    gasLimit: 30000000,
  });
  console.log("Result:", tx);
  tx.wait().then(async (receipt: any) => {
    console.log("Transaction confirmed in block:", receipt.blockNumber);

    const updatedReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(tx.hash);
    console.log(updatedReceipt);
  });
  return tx.hash;
}
try {
  //register channel
 await register(signedState, adj!, this.provider);
 this.listenToChannelUpdate(adj!);
} catch (err) {
 console.log("Error while register:", err);
 process.status = "failedRegister";
 process.error = new Error(
  ("Error while register: Invalid Signed State: " + err) as string
 );
 this.state.emitUpdateProcess(process.id);
}
```

If the Transaction fails, i would expect to see the Error with the added string: "Error while register..." but instead i get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0x829228b6c66278019247c93885b703958c0d7187b4c3307fe1a4cd03c5c495e1", transaction={"hash":"0x829228b6c66278019247c93885b703958c0d7187b4c3307fe1a4cd03c5c495e1","type":2,"accessList":null,"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0xA298Fc05bccff341f340a11FffA30567a00e651f","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0xee6b2800"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"B...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Error,it was because i tried to catch an error thrown inside of a promise with a try/catch-block which apparently i cannot do. After i changed the conclude function to throw the errors outside of the promise, it worked fine.